# How to make Pykka log directly to console?

Tags: python, logging, pykka

Pykka logs to a logger called `pykka`. I want all exceptions, debug messages printed to console, especially when running tests that start and stop actors in Pykka written with Mamba.

How do I do this?

Comment: I've found that the solution is nothing but the standard way of configuring logger.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to call `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause in whatever scripts run your tests, before the test runner is invoked. You can pass other keyword arguments to `basicConfig()` to control the formatting of messages, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).